# Nginx static files exclude one or some file extensions

Tags: nginx, static-content, exclude

I'm serving up a static site via nginx.

```
    location ~* \.(avi|bin|bmp|dmg|doc|docx|dpkg|exe|flv|gif|htm|html|ico|ics|img|jpeg|jpg|m2a|m2v|mov|mp3|mp4|mpeg|mpg|msi|pdf|pkg|png|ppt|pptx|ps|rar|rss|rtf|swf|tif|tiff|txt|wmv|xhtml|xls|xml|zip)$ {
        root /var/www/html1;
        access_log off;
        expires 1d;
    }
```

And my goal is to exclude requests like `http://connect1.webinar.ru/converter/task/`. Full view is like `http://mydomain.tld/converter/task/setComplete/fid/34330/fn/7c2cfed32ec2eef6788e728fa46f7a80.ppt.swf`. Despite the fact these URLs ends in such a format they are not static, but fake script requests, so I have a problems with them.

What is the best way to do this? How can I add an exclusion for this URL or maybe I can to exclude the specific file exptension (.ppt.swf, pptx.swf) from the list of this Nginx location?

Thanks.

Comment: Ou, and I forgot to add that the problem is that we have .swf format goes via Nginx. I need to exclude .ppt.swf, pptx.swf and same ext's only. I don't need to exclude .swf as a whole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
location ~* \.(?:avi|bin|bmp| ... |(?<!\.pptx\.|\.ppt\.)swf)$ {
    root /var/www/html1;
    access_log off;
    expires 1d;
}
```

.

```
$ man pcrepattern
$ man pcresyntax
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using regular expression in your location for static files, you can just add `!pptx?\.swf` condition to it  and exclude condition `swf`

Your location will look like this:

```
location ~* \.(avi|bin|bmp| ... |!pptx?\.swf)$ {
        root /var/www/html1;
        access_log off;
        expires 1d;
}
```

And don't forget to add separate location for `*.swf` files:

```
location ~* [0-9a-z]*\.swf$
        root /var/www/html1;
        access_log off;
        expires 1d;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can exclude a specific file or folder with this code in your NGINX configuration.

If you want to exclude specific file add this code

```
location / {
    rewrite ^/((?!manifest.json|pwabuildersw.js).*)$ /index.php?slug=$1 last;
}
```

If you want to ignore specific folder add this

```
location /assets {
  # Nothing here
}
```

Reference:- [Ignore or Exclude specific files or complete folder in NGINX](https://trinitytuts.com/tips/ignore-or-exclude-specific-files-or-complete-folder-nginx/)